# Is there a way to specify the format of dates with fread?

Tags: r, date, data.table, fread

Since 1.13, fread can automatically detect and read date types, which is really nice. I would like to detect dates if, and only if, they are in a specific format, but from what I have seen, fread only detects ISO-formatted dates with no option to change this.

```
> packageVersion('data.table')
[1] '1.14.0'    
> typeof(data.table::fread("date\n2020-10-10")[[1]])
[1] "integer"
> typeof(data.table::fread("date\n10-10-2020")[[1]])
[1] "character"
> typeof(data.table::fread("date\n10-10-2020", format = "%d-%m-%y")[[1]])
Error in data.table::fread("date\n10-10-2020", format = "%d-%m-%y") :
  argument inutilisé (format = "%d-%m-%y")
```

Is there a way to change the format of dates detected by fread or is it going to happen in the future? If not, could the option `datatable.old.fread.datetime.character` be made permanent to prevent that detection when it isn't wanted?

Comment: Not sure this is still the case but ["Dates and Datetimes are read as character columns but can be converted later with the excellent fasttime or anytime packages"](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/production/course_5323/slides/chapter5.pdf)

Comment: There's a [feature-request](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2402) to add the `format=` parameter for parsing. It's for `IDateTime`, but I'd think that if/when this gets implemented, it might be transferrable to other date/time classing as well.

Comment: @Waldi Thanks for the link, I've seen this but for my application with fread >=1.13 I would need to first convert ISO date columns back to character somehow, and use one of those separate packages to convert non-ISO date. It would be much simpler if we could specify the date format to fread.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks I missed that! I know that `as.IDate("10-10-2020", format = "%d-%m-%y")` already works. Hopefully a format parameter for fread would be easy to add.

Comment: you CAN do it directly in the fread line, if you first create a custom class with your valid date-time formats hard-coded. See https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/5006#issuecomment-1185862986